What are differences between 5XX, 5.* and 5.. for HTTPcode of PromQL/prometheus
In then Promql/Prometheus, we can pass 5xx, 5.* and 5.. in the query and check the http status. Sometimes are gives same results.
Eg.
http_requests_total{status!~"4XX"} or
http_requests_total{status!~"4.*"}
Here my question is that what are differences between them ?

AFAIK in  5xx the x is not a wild-card and that should only match the literal string with number 5 followed by two lower-case letters x - On the other hand 5.* and 5.. are both valid  RE2 syntax to define regular expressions  where . means "any character"  and adding the * modifier  "zero or unlimited occurrences of the previous element"   - Both 5.* and 5.. should match 500 and/or 5ab but 5.* will also match for example 5 and/or 5Q or 5 lines of code

http_requests_total{status!~"4XX"} 

In a list of three digit   HTTP status codes  excluding the literal 4XX will exclude nothing.
It is not impossible  that in a list with web server responses there are only valid HTTP responses. If that list doesn't contain a single  404 "file not found error" response nor any of the other server error responses from the 400 range, then using the valid  regular expression syntax  http_requests_total{status!~"4.*"} won't exclude anything either and you get the same results as with http_requests_total{status!~"4XX"}.
More likely is that the web server logs errors in a separate error log that doesn't het processed by your monitoring solution.
